# Multi-Column Pandas counting based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a list of 'words' I want to count below

```
word_list = ['one','two','three']
```

And I have a column within pandas dataframe with text below.

```
TEXT                                       | USER    | ID
-------------------------------------------|---------|------
"Perhaps she'll be the one for me."        | User 1  | 100
"Is it two or one?"                        | User 1  | 100
"Mayhaps it be three afterall..."          | User 2  | 150
"Three times and it's a charm."            | User 2  | 150
"One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish." | User 2  | 150
"There's only one cat in the hat."         | User 3  | 200
"One does not simply code into pandas."    | User 3  | 200
"Two nights later..."                      | User 1  | 100
"Quoth the Raven... nevermore."            | User 2  | 150
```

The desired output that I would like is the following below, where I want to count the number of unique users that has text related to any word in word_list, using the data found in the "TEXT" column. After counting the unique users, I also want to count the sum of the followers related to each tweet, associated with the unique user count of the word.

```
Word | Unique User Count | ID Sum
one  |      3            | 450
two  |      2            | 250
three|      1            | 150
```

Is there a way to do this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I break down steps

```
df.columns=['TEXT','USER','ID']

df[word_list]=df.TEXT.str.lower().apply(lambda x : pd.Series([x.find(y) for y in word_list])).ne(-1)
df1=df[['USER','one','two','three','ID']].set_index(['USER','ID']).astype(int).replace({0:np.nan})
Target=df1.stack().reset_index().groupby('level_2').agg({'USER':lambda x : len(set(x)),'ID':lambda x : sum(set(x))})
Target=Target.reset_index()
Target.columns=['Word','Unique User Count','ID Sum']
Target
Out[97]: 
    Word  Unique User Count  ID Sum
0    one                  3     450
1  three                  1     150
2    two                  2     250
```

Comment: Line 3: KeyError: 'level_2'

Comment: @Leggerless add this in the beginning df.columns=['TEXT','USER','ID'], your column name contain blank

Comment: @Leggerless `df1.stack().reset_index()` input this , show me your columns name